# In 1500 trials the correct answer was given 910 times. Is the conjecture plausible?

Tags: probability, random-variables

From Grimmett and Stirzaker's *Probability and Random Processes*, third edition, section "Two Limit Theorems", problem #2, page 200:

*It is well known that infants born to mothers who smoke tend to be small and prone to a range of ailments. It is conjectured that also they look abnormal. Nurses were shown selections of photographs of babies, one half of whom had smoker mothers; the nurses were asked to judge from a baby's appearance whether or not the mother smoked. In 1500 trials the correct answer was given 910 times. Is the conjecture plausible? If so, why?*

So I assume we are to interpret this as the sum of 1500 independent identically distributed random variables, which are equal to 1 if the nurse gets it right, and equal to zero if the nurse gets it wrong. We know that

$$\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\to N(0,1).$$

Assuming that there is no effect, the nurse would have a 50% chance of getting it right, which would mean all the random variables have mean $.5$ and $\sigma^2 = .5$. So here $\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}$ is something like $6$, which is obviously very unlikely if the convergence to $N(0,1)$ is good. How can we estimate how good the convergence is and justify our conclusion?

Comment: The nurses could be basing their judgment on an informed guess about weight.

Comment: Given that being small is certainly a part of a baby's appearance, it cannot be excluded that the nurse were in part basing their judgement on that. If "looking abnormal" is not specified in any way, and nurses were not asked to judge _that_ property (rather than having a smoking mother), I think the experiment is without relevance to the conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it with Hoeffding's inequality. Each observation $X_i$ is a draw of bernoulli random variable with unknown parameter $\theta$. Let $\hat \theta=\frac{1}{1500}\sum_{i=1}^{1500}X_i$. Then $\mathbb E \hat \theta=\theta$ and Hoeffding's inequality gives the following confidence region for $\theta$:
$$\mathbb P(\|\hat \theta-\theta\|\leq\epsilon)\geq 1-2e^{-2\epsilon^2n}$$
Here we observe $\hat p=\frac{910}{1500}$ which is $\frac{160}{1500}$ away from 0.5 so the p-value is
$$2e^{-2(\frac{160}{1500})^21500}\approx 3\times10^{-15}$$
which is tiny. So the null hypothesis (which could either have been $\theta=0.5$ or $\theta\leq0.5$) is thoroughly debunked in favor of the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Hold on $-$ we are missing a vital piece of data here! What proportion of mothers are smokers? If this proportion is as low as 39%, you can get a score of 910 out of 1500 simply by choosing non-smoker for all babies.
Without this data point, no conclusion at all can be drawn from the experimental data.

Comment: Half of the pictures were of babies whose mother's smoked.